# Show NavigationBar when scrolling down

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this simple code with a hidden NavigationBar but what I want is to show it when scrolling down. How can I do that?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 3) { _ in
                        Image(systemName: "rectangle.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .padding()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Title Here", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Update: Xcode 14 / iOS 16

Now `.navigationBarHidden(barHidden)` is animatable, and with old `NavigationView` and with new `NavigationStack`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var barHidden = true
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {  // << Tested !!
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
```

[image: demo]

[Test module is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/iOS16/TestShowNavBarWhenScrolling.swift)

#### Original

It is possible but this modifier is not animatable, so bar appears instantly (the same is observed when toggle bar with button). Anyway I think it worth posting.

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var barHidden = true

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 3) { _ in
                        Image(systemName: "rectangle.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .padding()
                    }
                }.background(GeometryReader {
                    Color.clear.preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self,
                        value: -$0.frame(in: .named("scroll")).origin.y)
                })
                .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) {
                    if !barHidden && $0 < 50 {
                        barHidden = true
                        print("<< hiding")
                    } else if barHidden && $0 > 50{
                        barHidden = false
                        print(">> showing")
                    }
                }
            }.coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
            .navigationBarTitle("Title Here", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarHidden(barHidden)
        }
        .animation(.default, value: barHidden)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct ViewOffsetKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGFloat
    static var defaultValue = CGFloat.zero
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value += nextValue()
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what i'm looking for but it's kinda weired that it doesn't anymate. But despite that very useful

Comment: I don't really understand what's going on in the code below, after GeometryReader, but I tried to copy and paste it to see if it works but I get this error "Use of unresolved identifier ViewOffsetKey"

Comment: Forgot to add `ViewOffsetKey`, it was in different module. In background we read offset of Vstack, scrollview content, in defined scrollview coordinate namespace, and store it in view preference key, then we read that value in onPrefereceChanged observer and decide by checking with specified limit (for demo it is used 50) if we should show bar or hide it.